# SVN collaboration failing

Tags: php, svn, version-control, versions

Today is the first day i'm playing with SVN.
However 1 situation i cant solve:

I checkout on 2 pc's
The first pc's Pc changes something in a file and commits.
The second pc then tries to commit:

```
Commit failed (details follow):
File '/classes/ghjs.html' is out of date
```

I have to run update on the second pc, it gets the new file from pc 1, then i can commit properly again, however changes done before updating are lost.

SVN isn't that awesome if you have to commit / update before you can write a line of code else other people working on te same file don't have you latest version.

I understand there isn't somethink for "live" collaboration, however there must be something that if you were working on a old version, instead of update you can manually "port" your changes to the latest version.

Im using "versions" as svn client and textwrangler as editor for editing php code.

Comment: You should try all of the above operations with the Subversion command line client and see what happens. (The changes will merge automatically or the file will be left in conflict in the working directory on PC 1.) Chances are Versions is misbehaving or you're using it incorrectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have to run update on the second pc,
>   it gets the new file from pc 1, then i
>   can commit properly again, **however
>   changes done before updating are lost**.

No, they aren't lost. They are *merged* into your local copy (just as you expect them to be), and after updating you can commit to add them to the repository. If the merge results in conflicts you will be notified, but still no work will be lost.

If you lost your changes after an update you did something wrong -- I 'm not familiar at all with Versions so I can't say.

Comment: Thank you. You are totally right. Useful link: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve.byhand
Useful menu/button: Action >Mark as resolved

Answer (score 0):

Local changes to files on pc 2 should not be lost on an `svn update`.  They will be merged with changes made on pc1 and committed.  If changes are made to the same lines in conflict, you will be unable to commit until the conflict is resolved, choosing to keep the changes from either of the file versions.  You should not lose local changes after updating though.

Answer (score 0):

Then you 'update' on PC 2, it should merge the changes from PC 1 into PC 2's working copy. If the file was edited on PC 2 then it should either cleanly merge them, or give a merge conflict and you can manually resolve them.

It is done this way so that SVN has a place to merge the 2 changes. Merges are done in a working copy, not on the server.

If your changes from PC2 are lost when updating, and no merge errors are shown, then that indeed could be a problem.